# Rails Omniauth Facebook login via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, omniauth-facebook, omniauth-google-oauth2

I have a rails application fully operating. I am using Devise, Omniauth, Omniauth Google and Facebook to login vai Facebook and Google and is working fine.

I am building mobile application for this application. For authentication on mobile I am using JWT-rails gem and I am able to log in, logout and browse the site.

So, I need to add the login with facebook/google option on mobile too but I am confused how to make an API to achive the goal. Please suggest me the best option.